# How to disable marking occurences in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, settings

Marking instances (occurrences)  of a variable always distracts me when coding. In Eclipse there was an option called **Toggle Mark Occurrences...** (or something like this) to disable/enable it.

Where can I find a similar option in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

Editor -> Highlight on Caret Movement -> **Highlight usages of element at caret**.

Disabling it did the job!

[image]